# EOFError: EOF when reading a line at input().split(), what can i do to fix this, python3

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys

arg = sys.argv
owner = arg[1]
keys = arg[2::1]
inside = list()
door = "LOCKED"

while True:
    inputs= input().split()

    if (inputs[0] == "INSERT" and inputs[1] == "KEY"):
            user = inputs[2]
            inserted_key=inputs[3]
            print ("KEY {0} INSERTED BY {1}".format(inserted_key,user))
            turn = input().split()
            house = input().split()
```

If I try to enter inputs manually myself, the program works fine. But if I use the `test.sh` file provided by my teacher, the program immediately breaks and gives me an EOFError when reading a line at input().split().

Any tips on how to fix? I would really appreciate it, thanks.

These are the commmands I enter normally:

./secure_house selina foobar

INSERT KEY adam key

TURN KEY adam

ENTER HOUSE adam

INSERT KEY pat foobar

TURN KEY pat

ENTER HOUSE pat

WHO'S INSIDE?

Here's the test.sh file I am using.

```
#!/bin/bash

set +x
set +e

echo "checking for README"
if [ ! -e "./README" ]
then
        echo "Error: No README file"
        exit 1
fi

echo "checking for Makefile"
if [ ! -e "./Makefile" ]
then
        echo "Error: No Makefile file"
        exit 1
fi

echo "Running make"
make
rc=$?
if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
then
        echo "Error when running the make command"
        exit 1
fi

if [ ! -e "./secure_house" ]
then
        echo "Error: Running make did not create the secure_house file"
        exit 1
fi

if [ ! -x "./secure_house" ]
then
        echo "Error: secure_house is not executable"
       exit 1
fi

INPUT_CASE="INSERT KEY adam key
TURN KEY adam
ENTER HOUSE adam
INSERT KEY pat foobar
TURN KEY pat
ENTER HOUSE pat
WHO'S INSIDE?
"

CORRECT_OUTPUT="KEY key INSERTED BY adam
FAILURE adam UNABLE TO TURN KEY key
ACCESS DENIED
KEY foobar INSERTED BY pat
SUCCESS pat TURNS KEY foobar
ACCESS ALLOWED
pat
"

echo "Testing your program"
OUTPUT=$( echo -n "$INPUT_CASE" | ./secure_house selina foobar)

DIFF=$(diff -aBw <(echo "$OUTPUT") <(echo "$CORRECT_OUTPUT"))
rc=$?
if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Error: did not pass the basic test case on the website."
    echo "$DIFF"
else
    echo "SUCCESS!"
fi
```

Comment: Check that the canned input contains enough lines to feed all the calls to input().

Comment: sorry I don't understand

Comment: Can you include your test.sh script? Can you include the command line you use when you input manually? You can take a screenshot of what you input.

Comment: Just added both

Comment: It's now clear that the code you posted first is just the beginning of a much longer script and there is probably some kind of mismatch between the script and the test input.  Readers here cannot debug that mismatch without seeing the whole script and even if you posted it, there might not be anybody who would want to do that analysis for you.  So you could try posing the whole script or you could try to debug it yourself.  When it blows up with EOFError, it should give you a stack trace that shows which input call failed.  That should give you a clue about where the mismatch is.